# How to revert Cheese 3.12.2 to 3.8.3?

Tags: 14.10

I want to revert my version of cheese, can someone explain how that operation is performed?

Comment: Remove it using `apt-get` and install it from source?

Comment: Did below answer help?  If yes, please click the ☑ next to it!  **;-)**

Answer (score 0):

Easy:

- Uninstall it using the software center
- Download the [.deb file for cheese](https://packages.qa.debian.org/c/cheese.html) that you would like
- double-click
- Ignore the warnings from software center.